# Placing cells in a collection view side by side in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

By default, the cells in a collection view will add space in between them in order to reach between the borders of the collection view. In an app I am making for iPad, I need to be able to force the cells side by side (spacing = 0). There is no method included as part of flow layout or collection view cell, so is there a way which I can do this?

Comment: Please post your code for collectionview

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for are the following properties of your flowLayout: `minimumInterimSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing`
If you set those to 0, there will be no spacing between items in the collectionView at all.

In code, you would normally do it like this (without Storyboards):

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    //
    // layout
    //

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing =  0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing      = 10

    //
    // collectionView
    //

    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

If you want to set those properties dynamically, implement the corresponding methods of UICollectionViewFlowLayout (should also work with Storyboards).

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController,
    UICollectionViewDelegate, 
    UICollectionViewDataSource,
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    // the rest of your code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Storyboard  then select CollectionViewFlowLayout and change Min Spacing to 0.

[image]

Comment: While this is correct it's also not very helpful at all. "... and change it" change what? To what? What does any of what you have said (or screenshotted) mean?